# Update jQuery dependency on Hangfire Dashboard

Tags: jquery, hangfire

It's possible under installed nuget package or we need to create a pull request?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to commit changes to the open-source project? Or are you just trying to make a small change to your local version?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to update jquery dependency on dashboard, if it's possible to update directly on my project or I need to update on project and generate new nuget package, etc

Answer (score 0):

The Hangfire GitHub project: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire

If you want to make changes to your local copy of Hangfire, you will have to download the source code from the GitHub project instead of using the NuGet. Then you can compile it locally and make all the changes you want.

The list of Hangfire releases on GitHub: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/releases

Alternatively you can report it as an issue on the Hangfire GitHub project. But then you would have to wait for the Hangfire developers to correct the issue. You can make the changes yourself and create a pull request, but then you still have to wait for the pull request to be merged and then for the developers to make a new official NuGet release.

The Hangfire GitHub issues section: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues

So with that, I suggest you go with the first option if you need it here and now.